# How do I insert this reord into loan table?Some attributes require SELECT statements?

Tags: oracle, select, sql-insert

I have a garage_manager table

```
CREATE TABLE garage_manager(
garage_code NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
man_id NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
specialisation_id NUMBER(4) NOT NULL
);
```

I'm trying to insert a row into the garage_manager table like this.Man_id is hard-coded.

```
INSERT INTO garage_manager VALUES(
(SELECT garage_code FROM garage WHERE garage_email = 'melbournec@rdbms.example.com'),
1,
(SELECT specialisation_id FROM manager_specialisation WHERE specialisation_type='S')
);
```

However, I'm getting the error "too many values"?

Comment: Can you please share the result of the following queries? (1) SELECT garage_code FROM garage WHERE garage_email = 'melbournec@rdbms.example.com' (2) SELECT specialisation_id FROM manager_specialisation WHERE specialisation_type='S'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there are multiple specialisation_ids that match `specialisation_type='S'`? If so, you need to aggregate that column in some way.

Another approach is to use `INSERT...SELECT` syntax.

```sql
INSERT INTO garage_manager (garage_code, man_id, specialisation_id)
SELECT garage.garage_code, 1, manager_specialisation.specialisation_id
FROM garage, manager_specialisation
WHERE garage_email = 'melbournec@rdbms.example.com' AND specialisation_type='S'
```

Note that if there are multiple matching garages or manager specialisations, then you will end up inserting multiple rows this way. You didn't provide enough information about your database schema to be able to tell if that might be a problem.

Comment: I only have one specialisation_id for one specialisation_type and one garage per garage_email. However, when I run your query I get man_id as invalid identifier?

Comment: You are doing a `cross join` between `garage` and `manager_specialisation` tables? It will add M*N number of rows.